# easyAutocomplete input box value gives search string and not complete string

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the easyAutocomplete function to populate a html input box. There is then an .change javascript function which uses the value of the input box to carry out some actions. However this has been faulty and I found that if I print out the value of the variable I assign to be the input box value it gives the partial string that I initially typed as opposed to the autocompleted one.

```
$("#nap2").change(function(event){
    var selected = document.getElementById("nap2").value;
    document.write(selected);
```

If for example the input box is 'Apple', i start typing 'App', apple shows up in the list and is then cicked. The document.write function then displays 'App' whereas I need the value of selected to be Apple, any ideas?

Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score -1):

This issue has been fixed in a newest version of EasyAutocomplete plugin. You can download it on the website http://easyautocomplete.com.